# IntelliJ IDEA misses tests in modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

I have a setup where an IDEA project has several modules and each module has its own JUnit tests.

When I'm right clicking in the Project view on each individual module and choose 'Run All Tests', the tests are run fine.

However, when I do a right click on the containing project and do a 'Run All Tests' there, **only** the test for **one of the modules** are executed.

Is that a bug or a feature?  What am I missing?

Thank you.

In response to comments, here's the setup in more detail:

The ***java8-playground*** is the umbrella project with 2 modules underneath (***anyMatch*** & ***flatMap***):

[image]

Both modules are configured to use JUnit5.

[image]

The Run configurations for both modules were auto-created by me right-clicking in the project view on each individual module root (***anyMatch*** & ***flatMap***) as well as on the project root (***java8-playground***).  Here's what the look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When executing all tests for the top level project (***java8-playground***), ONLY the tests for anyMatch module are executed:

[image]

The tests for the other module are not run.  The are executed fine when invoked independently:

[image]

So, when IDEA auto-creates the Run configuration based on the chosen context (project or module) of the right-click action, shouldn't it be smart enough to also **CORRECTLY** auto-populate the "Search for tests" option in the Run Configuration menu?

Classpath seems to be chosen correctly, but not the Search for Tests context.  Is that by design?

Comment: For which one of the modules are they executed?

Comment: For just one out of 2.  Looks like the first one in alpha order.

Comment: What JUnit version do you use? Could you please attach screenshot of your Run configuration?

Comment: Thanks for information! It should work fine if you change "Search for tests" to whole project. This setting is by design because usually users want to run all tests from parent project. So "single module" is preselected to avoid unexpected runs of all tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

Choose Run / Edit Configuration

- Search for tests -> In whole project
- Working directory -> your project directory

I hope that picture was helped you.

[image]